$\exp$ of a stopping time is integrable
Let $B_t$ be a real Brownian motion started from zero. For $a> 0$, define $$\sigma_a:= \inf_{t\geq 0}~\{t: B_t-t\leq -a\}.$$
Then do we have $$E \left[\exp\left(\frac{\sigma_a}{2}\right)\right]<\infty~?$$
The motivation is the second part of this exercise. I have already done part 1 and the first part of part 2 (where $\lambda \geq 0$). The part I don't understand is extending $\lambda$ down to $-1/2$:
"The fact that this formula remains valid for $\lambda \in [−1/2,0[
$ can be obtained via an argument of analytic continuation."
If I don't know that expectation is finite I can't use analytic continuation.

Exercise 3.28 $\quad$ Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be an ($\mathfrak{F}_t)$-Brownian motion started from $0$. Let $a > 0$ and $$\sigma_a = \inf \{t \geq 0 : B_t \leq t-a\}.$$

1. $\,$ Show that $\sigma_a$ is a stopping time and that $\sigma_a < \infty$ a.s.
2. $\,$ Using an appropriate exponential martingale, show that, for every $\lambda \geq 0$, $$E \left[\exp(-\lambda \sigma_a)\right] = \exp(-a(\sqrt{1+2\lambda}-1)).$$
The fact that this formula remains valid for $\lambda \in [-\frac{1}{2}, 0[$ can be obtained via an argument of analytic continuation.
3. $\,$ Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M_t = \exp \left(\mu B_t - \frac{\mu^2}{2}t\right)$. Show that the stopped martingale $M_{\sigma_a \wedge t}$ is closed if and only if $\mu \leq 1$. (Hint: This martingale is closed if and only if $E[M_{\sigma_a}] = 1$.)


Curious, which text is this from?

@SeanRoberson Le Gall Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus

Formula
By using the martingale $M_{t}=exp(\mu B_{t\wedge \sigma_{a}}-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2}t\wedge \sigma_{a})$, we get
$$1=E[M_t]=E[e^{\mu(\sigma_{a}-a)-\frac{\mu^2}{2}\sigma_{a} }1_{\sigma_{a}\leq t}]+E[e^{\mu B_{t}-\frac{\mu^2}{2}t }1_{\sigma_{a}\geq t}].$$
The first term converges to $E[e^{\mu(\sigma_{a}-a)-\frac{\mu^2}{2}\sigma_{a} }]$ by monotone convergence theorem. The second term, we claim goes to zero for some $\mu$. Since $\sigma_{a}\geq t$, we have $B_{t}-t\geq -a$ and so for $\mu\leq 0$
$$e^{\mu B_{t}-\frac{\mu^2}{2}t }1_{\sigma_{a}\geq t}\leq e^{-\mu a} e^{\frac{\mu}{2}(2 -\mu)t }1_{\sigma_{a}\geq t}. $$
This is bounded as long as $\frac{\mu}{2}(2 -\mu)\leq 0$ which follows from $0\geq \mu$. So also using that negative-drifted BM goes to negative infinity, the second term goes to zero by dominated convergence theorem.
Therefore, we are left with
$$E[e^{\frac{\mu}{2}(2 -\mu)\sigma_{a} }]=e^{\mu a}.$$
So by letting $-\lambda=\frac{\mu}{2}(2 -\mu)$, we get $\mu=1+\sqrt{1+2\lambda}$ or $\mu=1-\sqrt{1+2\lambda}$.
Analytic continuation: bounded
Here we consider the function
$$E(z):=E[e^{-z \sigma_{a}}]$$
for $Re(z)>-\frac{1}{2}$. First we need to show that this function is well-defined for all such $z$. As done in Le-Gall pg16 for the Gaussian case, we bound
$$|E[e^{-z \sigma_{a}}]|=|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zs}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi s^{3}}}e^{-(a-s)^{2}/2s}ds|\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-Re(z)s}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi s^{3}}}e^{-(a-s)^{2}/2s}ds\leq c_{a}e^{b_{a}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+Re(z)}},$$
for some constants $c_a>0,b_a<0$ by using that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}e^{-a^{2}s-\frac{b^2}{s}}ds=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{b}e^{-2ab}.$$
Analytic continuation: extending the formula
This means that $E(z)$ is well defined. It is also holomorphic in the region $D=\{Re(z)>-\frac{1}{2}\}$ since we can apply Morera's principle over closed loops $C$
$$\int_{C}E(z)dz=E[\int_{C}e^{-z \sigma_{a}}dz ]=E[0]=0.$$
On the other hand, the RHS expression $e^{-a(\sqrt{1+2z}-1)}$ is similarly holomorphic in that region. But since $E(z)=e^{-a(\sqrt{1+2z}-1)}$ along the line $\lambda\geq 0$, the identity theorem implies equality throughout domain $D$.
So that means we have it for $\lambda\in (-\frac{1}{2},+\infty)$.
Extension to $\frac{1}{2}$
Here we simply apply the monotone convergence theorem
$$E[e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma_{a}}]=\lim_{r\to \frac{-1}{2}}E[e^{-r \sigma_{a}}]=\lim_{r\to \frac{-1}{2}}e^{-a(\sqrt{1+2r}-1)}=e^{a}.$$

Thank you, I will try to understand this tomorrow.

Two questions:


Doesn't $e^{\mu B_{t}-\frac{\mu^2}{2}t }1_{\sigma_{a}\geq t}\leq e^{-\mu a} e^{\frac{\mu}{2}(2 -\mu)t }1_{\sigma_{a}\geq t} $ assume $\mu \leq 0$?


I don’t understand the last line. You say “the above constraints force $\lambda\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$.” But when $\mu \leq 0 or \mu \geq 2$, we have $\lambda \leq 0$, right?



@famousmortimer I agree we just need $\mu\leq 0$.

Your approach is basically the way you do the first part of part 2. the challenge is extending lambda up to 1/2

but when $\mu \leq 0$, $\lambda$ is also $\leq 0$

sorry your lambda is the negative of the lambda in the exercise, so it may cause confusion. i hope it's clear what i'm saying

Where did you find this density for $\sigma_a$: $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi s^{3}}}e^{-(a-s)^{2}/2s}$?  Page 16 in my copy of Le Gall is some unrelated exercises, and I coudn't find it in the first two chapters.

this is the density for hitting time for Brownian motion with drift pg. 141 in Le Gall. (By symmetry of BM it works for negative $a$ too)

Ah! so 2 chapters after the exercise!  I will add this to my short list of le gall errata.  thank you for your help!

@famousmortimer I am not sure if it is a mistake. There might be some different approach that doesn't use the density.
